# how to get latest captured image in universal windows application using c#

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-10-mobile

i am developing a solution where i have to capture image from my windows phone mobile application using CaptureElement after capturing image i should preview the image to the user after that if user click on Upload button then save this image name and path to the database.

I use this source code to capture and preview but it is showing me all the images.

```
string fileName = "Image.jpg";// TextBox
        fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);

        Windows.Storage.IStorageFile photo =
            await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync
            (fileName, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

        await mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync
            (Windows.Media.MediaProperties.ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), photo);

        CaptureBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        ImageView.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        previewElement.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        UploadBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        CancelBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;


        //Here i am htrying to access file from SD card
        // Get the Pictures library
        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder picturesFolder =
            Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> folders =
            await picturesFolder.GetFoldersAsync();

        foreach (StorageFolder folder in folders)
        {
            // Get and process files in folder
            IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
            foreach (StorageFile file in fileList)
            {
                Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bitmapImage =
                    new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();

                // Open a stream for the selected file.
                // The 'using' block ensures the stream is disposed
                // after the image is loaded.
                using (Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream fileStream =
                    await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
                {
                    if (file.DisplayName == fileName)
                    {
                        // Set the image source to the selected bitmap.
                        Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bitmapImages =
                            new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
                        bitmapImages.SetSource(fileStream);

                        ImageView.Source = bitmapImages;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

How can i do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understand you right solution is simple:

```
string fileName = "Image.jpg";// TextBox
    fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);

    Windows.Storage.IStorageFile photo =
        await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync
        (fileName, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

    await mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync
        (Windows.Media.MediaProperties.ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), photo);

    CaptureBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    ImageView.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    previewElement.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    UploadBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    CancelBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

using (Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream fileStream =
                await photo.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                    // Set the image source to the selected bitmap.
                    Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bitmapImages =
                        new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
                    bitmapImages.SetSource(fileStream);

                    ImageView.Source = bitmapImages;  
            }
```